# How to label/cite multiple images from Internet links in a paper?

Tags: citations

I am using a few images I found on Wikimedia Commons to vizualize something I explain in my paper. However, I am not sure how to cite and label them. I am using Chicaco (Author, Year) and am unsure how it should look like, should I put the links as foot notes, should I explain where I got them from in the text, should I include links in the label under the images...? Thank you!

Comment: Usually the answer to style questions is some variation on look at how they do it where you want to publish. Some journals have style guides. When it includes images the answer usually includes be sensitive to copyright.

Answer (score 2):

Since the figures are not your work, you need to cite them. Wikimedia commons pictures have authors and might even have years if you look at the edit history. You then cite them as you would cite any other web-resource, following your exact style guidelines.

Figure 5: The BGP State Machine [5].

References:
[5] Johannes Rössel, BGP State Machine, Wikimedia Commons,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol#/media/File:BGP_FSM.svg, 2008.